# NSPredicate, with quotes / without quotes

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

In my iPhone app, I'm reading a csv file. The relevant line is this:

```
NSString *countrycode = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:2]] 
                                 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

This returns "CN" (which stands for China).

When I do this:

```
NSLog(@"Manual: %@, country code: %@",@"CN",countryCode);
```

I get:

```
Manual: CN, country code: "CN"
```

One has quotes and the other does not. I don't know why this is.

The reason this is tripping me up is the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countrycode == %@ ", @"CN"];
```

This works fine, and returns China from Core Data.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countrycode == %@ ", countrycode];
```

This fails to return anything. I am assuming this is because it has quotes around it, or something, although perhaps I am incorrect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `countryCode` variable must have quotes inside of it when it's read back.  The first time you assign the literal `@"CN"` the quotes are removed as they specify that your variable is an `NSString`. They aren't really inside of the literal string.  If you wanted strings inside of the first CN, you'd need to explicitly specify the quotation marks, e.g. `@"""CN"""`

However, if you want to get rid of any quotations in the second string, you could always do this to the string prior to putting it into your predicate:

```
[countryCode stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"""" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Well, it's not that I want quotes inside of the first CN, it's that I don't want them inside of the second one. I think. Because it's screwing up the NSPredicate call. Right?

Comment: When you do an NSLog of the `countryCode`, does it contain quotes?

Comment: Yes, and it fails to return anything from Core Data

Comment: I used: [countrycode stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]; instead, and that did it. Thanks!

Comment: @thekevinscott Glad to hear! ;)

Answer (score 19):

Actually the correct way to format a predicate to exclude quotes is the to use `%K` versus `%@`. See [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Comment: THANK YOU! You have just saved me from CloudKit NSPredicate hell...